# Fetching Records to a Select Menu with a Section Header

Tags: php, mysql

my table is

```
Section SectionID   SectionHeader
S1      1           Section1
S2      1           Section1
S3      1           Section1
S4      2           Section2
S5      2           Section2
S6      3           Section3
S7      3           Section3
```

I am using following code for fetching records from DB.

```
<?php  $sql="SELECT * FROM myTable ORDER BY SectionID";
$result=mysql_query($sql); ?>
<select><option value="" selected="selected">Select a Section</option>
<?php   while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {?>
    <option value="<?php echo $row['SectionID'];?>" > <?php echo $row['Section'];?></option> <?php } ?> </select>
```

I would like to display each Sections with its Section Header in a Select Menu.

So my final output look like :

[image]

Please Help

Comment: Section Header will be select-able ?

Comment: *sidenote:* stop using deprecated `mysql_*` functions. use MySQLi or PDO instead.

Comment: Selection Header do not select.. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code

```
<?php  
$sql="SELECT * FROM myTable ORDER BY SectionID";
$result=mysql_query($sql); 
?>
<select>
    <option value="" selected="selected">Select a Section</option>
    <?php
    $section_id = 0; // this will be initialize here as zero.
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        if ($section_id != $row['SectionID']) {
        ?>
            <option value >----<?php echo $row['SectionHeader'];?>----</option> 
        <?php
            $section_id = $row['SectionID']; // set the value of $section_id as equal to $row['SectionID'] 
        }
        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row['SectionID'];?>" > <?php echo $row['Section'];?></option> 
    <?php } ?> 
</select>
```

**EDIT**
And for non select-able `SectionHeader`

```
<?php  
$sql="SELECT * FROM myTable ORDER BY SectionID";
$result=mysql_query($sql); 
?>
<select>
    <option value="" selected="selected">Select a Section</option>
    <?php
    $section_id = 0; // this will be initialize here as zero.
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        if ($section_id != $row['SectionID']) {
            if ($section_id != 0) {
                echo "</optgroup>"; // this code will not run for the first time, but from the next it will first close the last opened <optgroup> and than create a new <optgroup>
            }
        ?>
            <optgroup label="----<?php echo $row['SectionHeader'];?>---- ">
            <!-- the issue was here in the above code. optgroup have label to show as option header -->
        <?php
            $section_id = $row['SectionID']; // set the value of $section_id as equal to $row['SectionID'] 
        }
        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row['SectionID'];?>" > <?php echo $row['Section'];?></option> 

    <?php } ?>
    </optgroup> <!-- This will to close the last opened <optgroup> -->
</select>
```

Comment: Quick question, would it be possible for non selectable for section headers

Comment: My friend, this code shows blank space on the Section Headers (Not displaying it), it is non select-able. If possible plz check. -------- is also not displaying

Comment: I can't see any problem in the code but I've made changes to the code in the edit, can you please check it again?

Comment: I have made the change in the code. the issue was at `<optgroup>----<?php echo $row['SectionHeader'];?>---- ` it should be in rather a `label` attribute like `<optgroup label="----<?php echo $row['SectionHeader'];?>---- ">>`

Comment: Friend, a small change, If the SectionID is not in proper order, how can i arrange it.

Comment: your sql query `SELECT * FROM myTable ORDER BY SectionID` the `ORDER BY` is doing the ordering job, so I don't think there should be any ordering issue.

Comment: What you actually want to do?

Comment: Sorry, i found my problem..Sorry I am disturbing you a lot.

Comment: Its ok we are here to help